# How to use arraylist and arrays?What is the difference between them?In the following code which one to use?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

In the following code,we use a for-loop to get an array of latitudes and longitudes.How do we return(value) from this class ?How can i get latitudes and longitudes from the googleapiclass so that i can use in another class i.e. if we add them to an arraylist how will we retrieve them in another class.

```
 public class Googleapicall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

    {

        private ProgressDialog Dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationActivity.this);
            Dialog.setMessage(LocationActivity.this.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.loading));
            Dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Dialog.show();

        } 

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

             JSONObject jObject = null;

             String Url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location="+lat+","+lon+"&radius=5000&regions=postal_code&sensor=true&key="+Googlekey;

             try
             {

                 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  

                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(Url);
                    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                     resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  

                    if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                                //do something with the response
                        result=EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet, HTTP.UTF_8);

                                jObject =(JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result)
                                .nextValue();
                                getresults=jObject.getString("html_attributions");

                                JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("results");

                                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)

                                {

                                    Double longitude = ((JSONArray)jObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(i)
                                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                                .getDouble("lng");

                                    Double latitude = ((JSONArray)jObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(i)
                                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                                .getDouble("lat");

                                }


                    }

             }

             catch(Exception e)
             {

                 e.printStackTrace();
             }


            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You have a lot of different questions in your post and you don't show a lot of research effort. Maybe you could start by reading up on 'Array' and 'ArrayList'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 fields. U must create some simple class:

```
class TwoFields{
   public Double longitude;
   public Double latitude;
}
```

and put it to `ArrayList`, it is more handly.

if u want some response define `onPostExecute()`

Comment: but be careful to compare them. For this you must define hashCode() and isEquals() methods.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a constant array you can go for Array else its better to go for ArrayList as its easier to perform operations on it

Array is suitable when a constant memory block is needed to be allocated and size is not gonna change. ArrayList is better suited when the size may change dynamically